# How to redirect to another page from gridview edit event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I don't know am I using good approach.
I have a view page with `gridview` and edit page.
In gridview I have added:

```
...
<Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="true"></asp:CommandField>
...
```

And event:

```
OnRowEditing="rgrContact_RowEditing"
```

In event method I have tried to add:

```
protected void rgrContact_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            var id = (int)rgrContact.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value; 
            Response.Redirect("..." + id);
```

But there is no `e.RowIndex`.
How to get ID of the selected row so I can pass it to edit page?
Am I using good event?

Comment: Why not make the edit a link with querystring containing the id of the record

Comment: @1110 Why are you doing this, rather than doing what codingbiz says? There's no need to involve the server in this, you'd be much better off just having a HyperLinkField.

Comment: I didn't think about that approach. So I should make item template with hyperlink right? Can I get some example please.

Comment: You don't need an ItemTemplate. Just a [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield(v=vs.110).aspx). Learn to use MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`NewEditIndex` returns index of row on which you click for Edit

```
protected void rgrContact_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            var id = (int)rgrContact.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value; 
            Response.Redirect("MyEditPage.aspx?MyID=" + id);
```

EDIT:

```
DataKeyNames="DataKey1,DataKey2"
```

You can Use Like this

```
string DataKey1= rgrContact.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values[0].ToString();
string DataKey2= rgrContact.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values[1].ToString();
```

OR

```
rgrContact.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values["DataKey1"];
rgrContact.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values["DataKey2"];
```

As Others said No Need to Use what you said 
another solution :

```
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hyper" Text="this is link"
   NavigateUrl= '<%# String.Format("{0}","MYpage.aspx?id=" + Eval("MY_ID_COL")) %>' runat="server" /> 

   </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks that work. Can you tell me if there are multiple `DataKeys` then how to get both?